# Actually this is a code in swift 2.0, can someone tell me how to code these in swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, ios7, swift3, swift2

[image: This is the code that i cannot solve in swift 3.0. Please help me]

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDisChange searchText:String){
    filteredArray =tableData.filter({ names: String) ->Bool in
    return name.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(of: searchText.lowercaseString)
    })
}
```

Comment: Add your code as text!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    filteredArray = tableData.filter { (names) -> Bool in
        return (names.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much.

Comment: You can accept and upvote the answer if it worked.